# How to change the radio buttons based on selecting JCombobox item( In Java)

Tags: java, swing, selection, jcombobox, jradiobutton

How to change the radio buttons based on the selection of Jcombobox item like the royal, middle class, lower class:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnFh4.png]

Comment: Pls add some descriptions of your issue - what you need to do, what you already done and any error message you received.

Comment: Don't change the radio buttons. Instead change the entire panel. This allows you to define a unique panel for each meal type. Use a `Card Layout`. This will allow you to swap panels. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example that does exactly what you want.